# expect(...).toHaveAttribute is not a function despite properly extending it

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, detox, jest-dom

I have my test setup using `jest` and `detox` (@e2e)

Issue is, despite seemingly properly importing `@testing-lib/jest-dom`, I can't seem to use the `toHaveAttribute()` matcher as I should be able to.

---

**Inside my `spec.js` file:**

```
import { toHaveAttribute } from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

expect.extend({
  toHaveAttribute,
})

// ... tests here
```

However, when running my tests, I get the following error:

> TypeError: expect(...).toHaveAttribute is not a function

[image]

- As [you can see @ docs I should be setting up my `expect` properly.](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#usage). So I'm really confused as to why I'm getting this error.
- I found a [similar
  issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/379),
  but as you can see, I'm properly importing the `extend-expect` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native development is not DOM. Detox implements its own expectation API, which is routed to the appropriate platform's native implementation, and `toHaveAttribute()` is not implemented. We have no concrete plans currently to support this, but we will consider in the future, once a planned rewrite of the iOS side is completed.

Comment: given this, is there currently any way you expect users to check for values in checkboxes / radio buttons? As of now I'm struggling to think of anything with the current detox toolset, other than creating a hidden text that acts as a `state` text-checkbox, which will be checked for value.

Comment: I think toHaveValue should work. In any case, we will have a way to pull attributes into JS in the future.